# BPF samples in Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-kernel

`man bpf` states that

> Some complete working code can be found in the samples/bpf directory in the kernel source tree.

However I can't find any samples at that location:

```
$ uname -r
5.1.11-200.fc29.x86_64
$ ls /usr/src/kernels/5.1.11-200.fc29.x86_64/samples/bpf
Makefile
```

`sudo make` appears to error due to another cause, however it looks like the `Makefile` there expects the existence of samples in `samples/bpf` (`BPF_SAMPLES_PATH`):

```
$ cd /usr/src/kernels/5.1.11-200.fc29.x86_64/
$ sudo make headers_install
$ sudo make samples/bpf/
  HOSTCC  scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders
scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders.c:18:10: fatal error: classmap.h: No such file or directory
 #include "classmap.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:92: scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:486: scripts/selinux/genheaders] Error 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:486: scripts/selinux] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1069: scripts] Error 2
```

Also, [the remote linux kernel repo includes a README with examples](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/samples/bpf).

Are there BPF samples in the Fedora linux kernel directory? If so, where are they located?

Answer (score 0):

You need the installed LLVM packet to compile the sample programs to the byte-code, that will be executed by in-kernel virtual machine.

Also the kernel headers should be installed.

Comment: I've installed `clang` and `llvm`, and still get the `classmap.h` error (will update question) - however my question is aimed at the lack of sample programs in `samples/bpf`.

Comment: I've also run `make headers_install` from the base kernel directory (will update question) however the above still applies - .the `classmap.h` error still exists, however my question is aimed at the lack of sample programs in `samples/bpf`.